# How to count number of images available on a web page using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

How to count number of images available on a web page using selenium webdriver? The web page contains a lots of image some are visible and some are hidden (display:none). I only wants to count images which are visible(not hidden).

I tried this but it doesn't work for only visible images.

```
@Test
    public void imagetest()
    {
        driver.get("http://uat.tfc.tv/");
        List<WebElement> listwebelement = driver.findElements(By.className("img-responsive"));
        int i=0;
        for (WebElement Element : listwebelement) {
            i = i+1;
            System.out.println(Element.getTagName());
            System.out.println(Element.getText());

            String link = Element.getAttribute("alt");

            System.out.println(link);
        }
        System.out.println("total objects founds " + i);
    }
```

Comment: CSS also has `visibility:hidden`, do you want to ignore those as well?

Comment: In your loop you will need to test for the properties that determine if the image is hidden; if it isn't increment your counter, otherwise don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you wanted to find out the no. of images in a page, so better check with tag name like below:

```
driver.findElements(By.tagName("img")
```

Here is the complete code for your reference

```
@Test
    public void findNoOfDisplayeImages() throws InterruptedException
    {
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        Integer counter=0;
        driver.get("http://uat.tfc.tv/");
        Thread.sleep(20000);
        List<WebElement> listImages=driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"));
        System.out.println("No. of Images: "+listImages.size());
        for(WebElement image:listImages)
        {
            if(image.isDisplayed())
            {
                counter++;
                System.out.println(image.getAttribute("alt"));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("No. of total displable images: "+counter);
        driver.close();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply [`isDisplayed()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isDisplayed%28%29) check on each image element in the loop:

```
for (WebElement Element : listwebelement) {
    if (!Element.isDisplayed()) {
        continue;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package p1;

import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class CountImages {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/home/mcastudent/Downloads/software/geckodriver" );
         WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
         driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/index.php/dashboard");
         List<WebElement> listImages=driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"));
         System.out.println("No. of Images: "+listImages.size());

}
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.